# How to get the DataSourceId?

Tags: asp.net

```
private SqlDataSource GetDataSource()
       {

           object o = Session["selectedDataSource"];
           DataSourceType dsType = DataSourceType.Gtable;            

              if (o != null)
                   dsType = (DataSourceType)o;

              switch (dsType)
              {
                  case DataSourceType.tableT:
                      return DataSourceTID;
                  case DataSourceType.tableR:
                      return DataSourceRID;
                  case DataSourceType.tableC:
                      return DataSourceCID;
                  default:
                      return DataSourceCID;
              }        
       }
```

For getting the datasourceid I wrote that code.But that gives the error as "Specified cast is not valid".This error is arise at `dsType=(DataSourceType)`o line.
Please give me any suggextions.

Answer (score 0):

> Use enum parse method
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

```
DataSourceType dsType = (DataSourceType) Enum.Parse(typeof(DataSourceType), o);
```

Comment: In that we store the value from combobox